# Почему условие на отсутствие элемента в коллекции с NOT MEMBER OF всегда FALSE?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Есть коллекция, которая содержит пустой элемент. Когда проверяю условие, содержит ли эта коллекция несуществующий в ней элемент, она возвращает `false`, как и ожидалось.

Но странно то, что отрицание этого же условия также даст ответ `false`:

```
DECLARE
    TYPE number_t IS TABLE OF NUMBER;
    nt1 number_t := number_t();
BEGIN
    nt1.extend(2);
    nt1(1) := 2;
    dbms_output.put_line('Start');
    IF 2 member of nt1 THEN
        dbms_output.put_line('2 member');
    END IF;
    IF 1 member of nt1 THEN
        dbms_output.put_line('1 member');
    END IF;
    IF 1 NOT member of nt1 THEN
        dbms_output.put_line('1 NOT member');
    END IF;
END;
/
Start
2 member
```

В чём причина такого поведения, или что-то делаю не так?

---

<sub>Свободный перевод вопроса [PL/SQL negation of "member of" collection does not negate](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31460728) от участника [@Michael Lang](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2522681/michael-lang)</sub>

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/31460728

Answer (score 3):

В этом случае, `MEMBER OF` вернёт `NULL`.

Результат сравнения зачения с `NULL` не является ни `TRUE`, ни `FALSE`, а именно `NULL`.
Следовательно, ни одно из условий ниже, никогда не выполнится:

```
IF 1 = NULL THEN [...]
IF NOT 1 = NULL THEN [...]
```

---

Почему `MEMBER OF`, при наличии в коллекции одного единственного `NULL` элемента и отсутствии  проверяемого элемента, вернёт `NULL`, а не `FALSE`?  Потому что, оба метода определения, является ли элемент членом коллекции, в примере ниже - эквивалентны:

```
declare
    type numbertab is table of number;
    nt numbertab := numbertab (2, null);
begin
    dbms_output.put_line ('array is '||case when nt is empty then 'empty' else 'not empty' 
        end||' and has '||nt.count||' element(s)');

    dbms_output.put_line ('with member of result is '||
        case when (1 member of nt) is null then 'null' else 'not null' end);

    dbms_output.put_line ('with condition result is '||
        case when (1 = nt(1) or 1 = nt(2)) is null then 'null' else 'not null' end);
end;
/
array is not empty and has 2 element(s)
with member of result is null
with condition result is null
```

В документации о поведении [MEMBER OF](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/sqlrf/Multiset-Conditions.html#GUID-228D6708-37E1-4C54-8715-7EC2CF5B5998) в случае наличия `NULL` элемента, ничего не упомянуто:

> **MEMBER Condition**
> The return value is TRUE if expr is equal to a member of the specified nested table or varray.
> The return value **is NULL if expr is null or if the nested table is empty**.

---

Кого такое поведение не устраивает, может воспользоваться функциями по работе с `NULL`:

```
declare
    type numbertab is table of number;
    nt numbertab := numbertab (2, null);
begin
    dbms_output.put_line ('1 is '||
        case when NOT coalesce (1 member of nt, false) then 'not member' end);
    dbms_output.put_line ('2 is '||
        case when     coalesce (2 member of nt, false) then 'member' end);
end;
/
1 is not member
2 is member
```